# Stop playing sound media on click

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to add two sound shapes to a PowerPoint slide, both triggered on click, using PowerPoint VBA (Microsoft 365 MSO).

The slide timeline will be:

1. First click starts playing sound
2. Second click stops the first sound and starts the second.

I am able to place the sound shapes and add the animation objects to trigger the sounds.

I can't find the effect object property which replicates the GUI option to stop playing on click.
[image: GUI option to stop playing on click]

The code will add a new slide, create two sound shapes and have them trigger on click, however sound 1 does not stop playing.

```
Sub TestSoundTrigger()

    Dim slTestSoundSlide As Slide
    Dim shSoundShape1 As Shape
    Dim shSoundShape2 As Shape
    Dim efSoundShape1 As Effect
    Dim efSoundShape2 As Effect

' Create the slide
    Set slTestSoundSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(1))

' Add 2 sound shapes
    Set shSoundShape1 = slTestSoundSlide.Shapes.AddMediaObject2(ActivePresentation.Path & "\testsound1.mp3", True, False, 10, 10)
    Set shSoundShape2 = slTestSoundSlide.Shapes.AddMediaObject2(ActivePresentation.Path & "\testsound2.mp3", True, False, 10, 10)
    
' Add the 2 triggers to play the sounds on click in turn
    Set efSoundShape1 = slTestSoundSlide.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(shSoundShape1, effectId:=msoAnimEffectMediaPlay)
    Set efSoundShape2 = slTestSoundSlide.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(shSoundShape2, effectId:=msoAnimEffectMediaPlay)

End Sub
```

I've checked the Effect and the Timeline object properties but I can't find this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this property: ppSoundStopPrevious
[ppSoundEffectType](https://bettersolutions.com/powerpoint/macros/enumerations-ppsoundeffecttype.htm)

Alternatively 
You could set another msoAnimEffectMediaStop - but this would create another animation step

```
    Sub TestSoundTrigger()

    Dim slTestSoundSlide As Slide
    Dim shSoundShape1 As Shape
    Dim shSoundShape2 As Shape
    Dim efSoundShape1 As Effect
    Dim efSoundShape2 As Effect

' Create the slide
    Set slTestSoundSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(1))

' Add 2 sound shapes
    Set shSoundShape1 = slTestSoundSlide.Shapes.AddMediaObject2(ActivePresentation.Path & "\testsound1.mp3", True, False, 10, 10)
    Set shSoundShape2 = slTestSoundSlide.Shapes.AddMediaObject2(ActivePresentation.Path & "\testsound2.mp3", True, False, 10, 10)

' Add the 2 triggers to play the sounds on click in turn
    Set efSoundShape1 = slTestSoundSlide.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(shSoundShape1, effectId:=msoAnimEffectMediaPlay)
    Set efSoundShape1 = slTestSoundSlide.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(shSoundShape1, effectId:=msoAnimEffectMediaStop)
    Set efSoundShape2 = slTestSoundSlide.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(shSoundShape2, effectId:=msoAnimEffectMediaPlay)

End Sub
```